# How can I make this graphic more like a spark?

Tags: logo, critique

[image: spark graphic]

Can anyone suggest what I can add to this graphic to make it suggest a spark? At the moment it looks more like a star to me. Thanks!

EDIT Thanks very much for the suggestions, think it's looking better...
[image]

Comment: Well, first of all sparks do not have definite edges. So they rather go randomly in any possible direction. You can try turning those edges to left or right, lengthening and shortening some of them, and maybe add a few. But in the meantime it shouldn't be cluttered with too many graphics to ensure readability. So... try and see what works best.

Comment: Hi Nancy. Do you have examples of what the spark should look like? I'm having trouble understanding your problem, can you please explain more, including what you have tried? Thanks!

Comment: zig-zag arrows (resembling lightning strokes) going in several directions.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I should have included the context. It's a logo graphic for a company with 'spark' in the title, they want it to suggest sparking ideas, creativity etc. And the client likes the triangle graphic style.

Comment: Colors are backwards. Sparks are bright white at the center than fade to orange, red, blues at the edges. [do a google image search to see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2eazl.jpg) Sparks do not have a violet/blue center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can try avoiding repeat the pieces in the same direction, if you see the all of the pieces are going in the same direction, you should move them randomly.
I mean don't do that ( >>>> ) rotate each circle of pieces.

also can change the opacity, farder lighter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you DO need less defined edges, a darker background and more of a glow around the colors. I can attach a sample screen and do have a simple psd if this site allows me to send it.[image]